# How to specify the plugin version in the plugin.properties file of an Plugin project?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have a plugin project and it has a corresponding version in it, the version can be seen from opening META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, and switching to Overview tab. This tab has a field called version. 
[image]
Now in the plugin.xml file I am using some constants and hence I created a plugin.properties made required changes for properties file to be picked up. Now the constants are read properly from the properties file, but I want to have this version number in one of the places in plugin.xml, so I have hardcoded this value in plugin.properties file. Now every time I have to change the version number, I need to update in MANIFEST.MF and in plugin.properties.
Is there any variable that can be specified instead of hardcoding the value in properties? Or is there any other way? Using maven changing is not an option for me, I want to have this version at only place.

Comment: The version must be specified directly in the MANIFEST.MF. It is possible to read this version in your plugin code if that is what you want.

Comment: But how can I specify this version in the properties file? I have to hardcode it there? So tomorrow when I am updating version I'll have to change at both places right?

Comment: If you insist on putting the version in the properties file then yes you will have to remember to update it. You could use Ant of something like that to update both.